# on using nslookup error DNS request timed out is shown

Tags: networking, dns, wireshark

In wireshark I tried  `nslookup www.aiit.or.kr bitsy.mit.edu`, I think there is an error
(Please correct me if I'm wrong). Its displaying `dns request timed out timeout was 2 seconds`.
Here I  indicate that we want the query sent to the DNS server
"bitsy.mit.edu" rather than to the default DNS server

I'm a beginner to computer networks. I don't know the exact error occured, can anyone please explain to me why this happened. Please excuse me if my information is insufficient and incorrect. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is off-topic since it's not related to programming. It's best suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myself got the answer...

the dns protocol is built upon udp transport layer, generally the dns timed out is because of blocking the udp segments by the firewall of that institute bitsy.mit.edu se